# “Grant File Access” dialog in Word 2016+AppleScript when inserting a picture

Tags: applescript

Please Help!!

I have been using FMP to insert images into a word document by using apple script. This has been working fine until today (recent word update occurred and the likely culprit). When the script runs I get a dialog box saying that Microsoft Word needs to be “Grant File Access”. I approve and then it will work all the time with that file. Once a new file is created, I get the same issue.

This is frustrating beyond belief. I am running FMP 18 on Mac OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave).

"set ScaledReportImages to " & "\"" & Procedure_Pictures::Picture_Filename_Report_Path & "\"" & ¶ & 
"tell application " & "\"Microsoft Word\"" & ¶ & 
"   tell active document" & ¶ & 
"       set x to text object of cell " & $Cnt & " of row 1 of table " & $TblCnt & ¶ & 
"       make new inline picture at before x with properties {file name:ScaledReportImages as text, save with document:true}" & ¶ & 
"   end tell" & ¶ & 
"end tell" &¶ & ¶ &

"tell application " & "\"Microsoft Word\"" &¶ &
"   set content of text object of (cell " & $Cnt & " of row 2 of table " & $TblCnt & " of active document) to " & "\"" & Procedure_Pictures::Diagnosis_Keyword_Link_DISPLAY & "\"" & ¶ & 
"end tell"

Thanks
Spiro

Comment: Hi spiro, welcome to Ask Different. Is FMP by any chance "FileMaker Pro"? The issue you mention seems to be a file system access restriction. You can give Word full disk access as follows: open System Preferences, select Security & Privacy, select the Privacy tab, scroll down to Full Disk Access, add Word and restart Word. After doing so, could you try again and report back?

Comment: Is this in a shell script?  Please fix the formatting of your script - can hardly tell what that is supposed to be.

Comment: @red_menace It is AppleScript, and yes, the formatting makes it unnecessarily cryptic.